# Background image x position based on screen resolution

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

I need to place a background image in the center of the screen + some offset based on the screen resolution to make it work with a design element. Here's what I have so far:

```
var viewportWidth = jQuery(window).width();
jQuery('.home #container').css('background-position-x', viewportWidth/2);
```

What I'd like to know now is how to offset the background image now depending on the screen size.

**EDIT: Rephrase.**

I need to position a background image in the center of the screen based on the screen width (at the time of render) to make it work with a design I've done. Here's what I have so far:

```
var viewportWidth = jQuery(window).width();
jQuery('.home #container').css('background-position-x', viewportWidth/2);
```

I then need to offset that background image slightly, based on whatever monitor someone is using, so example:

1024 monitors: background-position-x: center + 24

1152 monitors: background-position-x: center + 32

1400 monitors: background-position-x: center + 102

something like that.

Many thanks!

Comment: `.css('background-position-x', (viewportWidth/2)-offset)` ??

Comment: you already got that, right? `jQuery(window).width()` gives you the screen size. If you're talking about actual size in centimeters, that's just not possible. You would need the exact size of the display area of the monitor, which it not available in the OS and especially not in the browser.

Comment: your viewportWidth is the screen width, so what do you mean by "screen size"?

Comment: Hi everyone. I have made an EDIT to hopefully clear things up a little?